# Access-VBA check if the cursor in a Textbox is in the first or last line

Tags: ms-access, vba

**The Goal:** I've got an Access database with a continuous form and I want to add the functionality that you can go to the next or previous record by pressing the up- or down-arrow.

**The Problem:** I've got a multiline TextBox named `txtProjekt` and I want the database to check if the TextBox is filled with multi-lined text and only jump to the next record if the cursor is in the last line of the TextBox.  Likewise I want it to only jump to the previous record if the cursor is in the first line of the TextBox.

I can only check the current cursor position with `SelStart`, but I can't find out in which line the cursor is.

Do you have any ideas?

**Current code:**

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
On Error GoTo err_Form_KeyDown

If Me.ActiveControl.Name = "txtProjekt" Then
    If Not (Me.txtProjekt.SelStart = 0 And Me.txtProjekt.SelLength = Len(Me.txtProjekt.Text)) Then
        GoTo exit_Form_KeyDown
    End If
End If

If KeyCode = vbKeyUp Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject, Record:=acPrevious
    KeyCode = 0
ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyDown Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject, Record:=acNext
    KeyCode = 0
End If

exit_Form_KeyDown:
Exit Sub

err_Form_KeyDown:
MsgBox Err.description
Resume exit_Form_KeyDown
End Sub
```

edit:
**The Result** (thanks to @Newd):

(be sure to active KeyPreview in your Form, otherwise it won't do anything)

```
Private Sub Form_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
On Error GoTo err_Form_KeyUp

If Shift = False Then
    keyAction KeyCode, True
End If

exit_Form_KeyUp:
Exit Sub

err_Form_KeyUp:
MsgBox Err.description
Resume exit_Form_KeyUp
End Sub

Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
On Error GoTo err_Form_KeyDown
Dim curPos As Integer

If Shift = False Then
    keyAction KeyCode, False
End If

exit_Form_KeyDown:
Exit Sub

err_Form_KeyDown:
MsgBox Err.description
Resume exit_Form_KeyDown
End Sub

Private Sub keyAction(KeyCode As Integer, KeyUp As Boolean)
On Error GoTo err_keyAction
Static curPos As Long

If KeyUp = False Then
    If Me.ActiveControl.Name = "txtProjekt" Then
        If Not (Me.txtProjekt.SelStart = 0 And Me.txtProjekt.SelLength = Len(Me.txtProjekt.Text)) Then
            curPos = Me.txtProjekt.SelStart
            GoTo exit_keyAction
        End If
    End If
Else
    If Me.ActiveControl.Name = "txtProjekt" Then
        If curPos >= 0 Then
            If Me.txtProjekt.SelStart <> curPos Then
                GoTo exit_keyAction
            End If
            curPos = -1
        Else
            GoTo exit_keyAction
        End If
    End If
End If

If KeyCode = vbKeyUp Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject, Record:=acPrevious
    KeyCode = 0
ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyDown Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject, Record:=acNext
    KeyCode = 0
End If


exit_keyAction:
Exit Sub

err_keyAction:
MsgBox Err.description
Resume exit_keyAction
End Sub
```

(I know, all those `GoTo Exit_keyAction` is bad style, so don't copy too much from me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't currently have the time to write this code out in full to incorporate your code as well.  However I think if you were able to get to the point you are at right now you should be able to utilize it.

Basically it is just a way to tell if the user has hit the end or beginning of the Multi-line textbox.

```vb
Public intOnDown As Integer
Public intOnUp As Integer

'When the user presses key down
Private Sub txtProjekt_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode = vbKeyUp Or KeyCode = vbKeyDown Then
        'Save the cursor position
        intOnDown = txtProjekt.SelStart
    End If

End Sub

'When the user lets go of the key
Private Sub txtProjekt_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode = vbKeyUp Or KeyCode = vbKeyDown Then
        If intOnDown - txtProjekt.SelStart = 0 Then 'If the SelStart is the same
            Debug.Print "Pointer hasn't moved so must be at the end or beginning"
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

With the above code you listen for when the user has pressed the up or down key on `Keydown` then you listen again on `KeyUp` (When they let go of the key). Then you check to see if the `SelStart` has changed.  If it hasn't then it must mean they are at the beginning or the end of the field and you can perform the record switching.

**Note:** Adjust accordingly if you have memo fields that are going to be over the max `integer` size by changing to a `long` and you probably want to have error handling for it regardless.

Comment: Hi Newd, thank you so much for your answer. I made it a bit different because the whole Form should listen to keypresses and i didn't want to have another public variables, but your answer helped me solve my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: @Dorian No problem.  After reviewing your answer history I figured you knew how to handle it once you got past the roadblock of how to tell if you hit the end of the textbox.  It was a very interesting question.

Comment: @Dorian Also, could you post your finalized code, I am interested in reading it.

Comment: the code is too Long to post it as a comment, so i will add another answer.

Comment: @Dorian even if you want to just edit your main post and throw it in there as an `Update`.